# allow to accept multiple validator patterns in angular material 2

Tags: angularjs, validation, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to use **[md-error](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#error-messages)** in angular material to validate user inputs from client side.

So in my case I'm trying to validate an input field that accept two types of patterns.

1. Regular Expression 1 : Accept first 9 characters as numbers then 10th
   character as **x** or **X** or **v** or **V**
2. Regular Expression 2 :  Accept 12 characters as numbers

So I implemented that in my typescript file like following

**samplefile.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

const NIC_REGEX_OLD = /[0-9]{9}[x|X|v|V]$/; // Regular Expression 1
const NIC_REGEX_NEW = /[0-9]{12}$/;         // Regular Expression 2

@Component({
    selector: 'sample-form',
    templateUrl: `sample.html`,
    styleUrls: ['sample.css']
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }       

    sampleFormControl = new FormControl('', [
        Validators.pattern(NIC_REGEX_OLD)
    ]);    
}
```

this is the HTML content for the above field

```
<div class="sample">
    <md-form-field>
        <input mdInput required [formControl]="sampleFormControl" maxlength="12">
        <md-error *ngIf="sampleFormControl.hasError('pattern')">
            Please enter the valid sample input
        </md-error>
    </md-form-field>
</div>
```

for a single regular expression(single pattern) this is working fine, but since I need to validate two patterns I tried following approaches in typescript file

**Approach 1:**

```
    sampleFormControl = new FormControl('', [
        Validators.pattern(NIC_REGEX_OLD || NIC_REGEX_NEW)
    ]);
```

**Approach 2:**

```
    sampleFormControl = new FormControl('', [
        Validators.pattern(NIC_REGEX_OLD),
        Validators.pattern(NIC_REGEX_NEW)
    ]);
```

But none of above working properly, is it possible to validate multiple patterns using md-error ? please comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you were trying was combination of pattern(`AND` condition) should satisfy together then only the field will be valid. But actually you need either of `RegEx` to be satisfied, so that's why consider creating a custom `validator` which would manually testing both the RegEx with `OR` operator.

**Code**

```
function validateInput(c: FormControl) {
  let NIC_REGEX_OLD = /[0-9]{9}[x|X|v|V]$/; // Regular Expression 1
  let NIC_REGEX_NEW = /[0-9]{12}$/;         // Regular Expression 2

  return (NIC_REGEX_OLD.test(c.value) || NIC_REGEX_NEW.test(c.value)) ? null : {
    validateInput: {
      valid: false
    }
  };
}

//Usage
sampleFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    validateInput
]);
```

See Also [**Custom Validators in Angular**](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: okay I'll go with that, really appreciate, thanks for the help

Comment: for this custom error how to show custom error message ?

Comment: Thanks Pankaj,

instead of test() method, I used match() in Angular 7.

   if(control.value.match(mob_Regex) || control.value.match(email_Regex)) {
         return null;
     }
     else {
         return  {checkValidAddress : true} ;
     }

Answer (score 0):

Write your two regex expression in single string using `|` and then use a single `Validators.pattern ("your expression")`.

Here it can be `Validators.pattern("/[0-9]{9}[x|X|v|V]$/|/[0-9]{12}$/")`.
Note here I have used an or between two regex.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 7 or above, you can do the following:

```
validateInput(c: FormControl){ //Dual Pattern Check 
    let oldPattern = '^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-HJ-NP-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{4}$'; // Regular Expression 1 
    let newPattern = '^[0-9]{2}BH[0-9]{4}[A-HJ-NP-Z]{1,2}$'; // Regular Expression 2 
    return (c.value.match(oldPattern) || c.value.match(newPattern)? null :{checkValidAddress : true}); }

//usage like this 
registrationNumber: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,this.validateInput])
```